# function bind_param() on boolean

Tags: php, mysqli

I have this code, a simple retrieve mysql data, but I receive this error upon submit.

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function bind_param() on boolean
```

I know that there is alot of solution, but I can't seems to find where is the problem coming from

Here is my code:-

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "poke", "password", "pokedb");

    if (isset($_POST['poke_name'])) {

    $query = "SELECT name,lat,long,pic,description FROM creature WHERE name LIKE ?";
    $param = "%{$_POST['poke_name']}%";

    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare($query);
    $stmt->bind_param("s", $param);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->bind_result($name, $lat, $long, $pic, $description);

        /* fetch values */
        while ($pokeinfo = $stmt->fetch_assoc()) {
            $poke_info[] = $pokeinfo;
        }

        /* close statement */
       $mysqli->close();

    }
```

Comment: The prepare has failed. Test the status returned by the prepare and then echo `$mysqli->error()`

Comment: Now that's funny I received this:
`Fatal error: Call to undefined method mysqli::error()`

Comment: Sorry see answer it should be `$mysqli->error` no `()`

Answer (score 0):

The prepare has failed. Test the status returned by the prepare and then echo `$mysqli->error`

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "poke", "password", "pokedb");
/* check connection */
if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", $mysqli->connect_error);
    exit();
}

if (isset($_POST['poke_name'])) {

    $query = "SELECT name,lat,long,pic,description FROM creature WHERE name LIKE ?";
    $param = "%{$_POST['poke_name']}%";


    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare($query);
    if ( $stmt === false ) {
        echo $mysqli->error;
        exit;
    }
```

Comment: Now that's funny I received this: Fatal error: Call to undefined method mysqli::error()

Comment: After update, I received this
`You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'long,pic,description FROM creature WHERE name LIKE ?' at line 1`

Comment: Tested, connection is not an issue

Comment: Well now you know where the error is. Does that query run in phpMyAdmin?

Comment: Hmmm, tested phpmyadmin, doesn't work either. What could be the problem with the query then?

Comment: Does that database exist? Does the table exist in the database? Do all the columns exist in the table

Comment: Yes it exist, I see, if I run `SELECT * 
FROM  creature 
WHERE name LIKE  '%Pikachu%'` it works

Comment: Then maybe the column names are wrong, check your schema

Comment: I'm not sure what happen, I solved it already. According to mysql, `long` is a keyword, I think that is the cause of it. My query consist of `long`, so I change the column name to something else, it seems there are other problems, but I managed to solved it already thanks anyway!

Comment: Thats the best solution. Or you can wrap the keyword in backticks

Answer (score 0):

Your query can be modified this way:

```
$query =  "SELECT name,lat,long,pic,description FROM creature WHERE name LIKE '%?%'";
$param =  $_POST['poke_name'];
```

You should debug your code. Try this:

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare($query) or die($mysqli->error);
var_dump($stmt); // Should return true if query executes
```

Run this in phpmyadmin:

```
SELECT name,lat,long,pic,description FROM creature WHERE name LIKE '%a%';
```

If this runs successfully, then there's something wrong with the prepared PHP code.

Comment: Now that's funny I received this: Fatal error: Call to undefined method mysqli::error()

Comment: Gotta use $mysqli->error instead of $mysqli->error(). Let me know what you're getting now. It will show an SQL syntax error if there's any.

Comment: Apparently is the query issue, not sure where is the problem though